# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, replace

Cant figure out why IE is showing this error message on the line below:

```
this.innerHTML.replace('#','').trim()
```

I used getElementsByClassName and looped through all  tags and attempting to remove the hashtag from the innerHTML of the link.

Works great in all browsers other than IE.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) an option? As this will perform some checks and use fallbacks when Javascript's `.innerHTML()` fails.